# String interpolation with actual % in string

Tags: ruby, string-formatting

What's the right way to deal with this?

```
"Hi %s, today is %s so you get 10% OFF!" % ['Joe', 'Monday']
# => ArgumentError: malformed format string - %O
```

I can't use normal `%{keyname}` or `#{code}` because I'm parsing strings for urls and stripping them out so I can stick them back in different formats (with/without protocol, shortened, full length, etc). So the number of replacements is unknown and they don't have names. They are just an array of urls.

I also tried escaping the `%`:

```
"Hi %s, today is %s so you get 10\% OFF!" % ['Joe', 'Monday']
# => ArgumentError: malformed format string - %O
```

but get the exact same result.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Two %'s

```
>> "Hi %s, today is %s so you get 10%% OFF!" % ['Joe', 'Monday']
=> "Hi Joe, today is Monday so you get 10% OFF!"
```

Comment: In the docs on the String class point you to Kernel::sprintf for all the formatting options. It's pretty universal in sprintf implementations.

Comment: Here is the Kernel::sprintf documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

Answer (score 1):

```
 "Hi %s, today is %s so you get 10%% OFF!" % ['Joe', 'Monday']
```